# jQuery not appending correct element

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm working on a way to display images of products and once an image is clicked, I want it to be displayed bigger. I get the images by a Soap call that looks like this:

```
$xml_params = "
<products>
    <sku>" . $sku . "</sku>
</products>";

$soapVar = new SoapVar($xml_params, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null);
$images = $this->soapClient->getProductImages(new SoapParam($soapVar, "getProductImages"));

return $images;
```

The `$sku` variable is passed to the above function when calling it.

To display the pictures I have the following html/php

```
<div class="art_images">
    <div class="active">

    </div>

    <div class="small_images">
    <?php
        for($x=0; $x < count($images->image); $x++) {
            echo '<img src="' . $images->image[$x]->url . '" class="small_image" id="' . $x . '"></img>';
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

To switch which picture's displayed bigger, I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.small_image').click(function() {
        var myId = $(this).attr('id');
        var myElement = $('.small_image').get(myId);
        $('.active').empty();
        $(myElement).clone().appendTo('.active');
    });
});
```

This works partially. It does display the picture that's clicked, but once I click another picture, it shows the picture with the id - 1. So if I click the picture with an id of 7, it displays the picture with the id of 6. If I `console.log(myId)` the correct id is displayed (so in the example above 7), but when I `console.log(myElement)` it shows the wrong element (so the element with the id of 6). Any idea how this is happening?

Comment: Why do you use `get` and all the other stuff at all, why not just `$(this).clone().appendTo('.active')`

Comment: And you could remove the `empty` with `$('.active').html( $(this).clone() ):`

Comment: Thanks, I'm still very new to jQuery so that's probably why I did it like that. Just one more problem though: when I try it on my mobile phone, nothing happens when clicking on the images. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Nevermind, found out I was using an old version of jQuery. With a newer one it works fine.